# robocopy ERROR 1314 (0x00000522) on Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, robocopy

I'm using a robocopy script with the switches /COPYALL and /B on my Windows 7 Home Premium PC to backup files to a NAS and I'm getting the error message:

> ERROR 1314 (0x00000522) Copying NTFS Security to Destination File *(file-location/name)* required privilege is not held by the client.

I think it is something to do with account privileges in Windows 7 Home Premium - I read somewhere you need to add the account to the Backup Operators group - but that is for the Server OS.

How can I overcome this problem without upgrading to Windows 7 Pro?

*Note:  The other Win 7 computer on the network which is Pro does not have this issue.*

Comment: Download the [Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657). Extract the `rktools.exe` downloaded file using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). Then extract `rktools.msi`. Among all the files there's one called `ntrights.exe`. To grant backup privileges to a specific user, run this command from an [elevated command prompt](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/command-prompt-faq#1TC=windows-7): `ntrights.exe -u "some_user_name" +r SeBackupPrivilege`

Answer (score 1):

this option should solve the problem and will copy the attributes required.
`/COPY:DATSO`

Here is more description on this

> /COPY:copyflag[s] :: what to COPY for files (default is /COPY:DAT).
>
> (copyflags : D=Data, A=Attributes, T=Timestamps).
>
> (S=Security=NTFS ACLs, O=Owner info, U=aUditing info).

Comment: It's the 'U' option which causes the failure

Comment: @smirkingman hey, I did not understand what you mean by causing failure. can you explain?

Comment: For me, DATSO worked but DATSOU failed. I concluded that 'U' was the problem